# Remove \r from string

Tags: c#, string

I have some Html in string I have tried utmost to remove \r many times but fails.

```
text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: This may be a silly question, but it's worth asking.  Are you trying to remove a carriage return or are you trying to remove the literal string "\r"?

Comment: Maybe you need to remove `<br>`/`<br />` tags instead. Or, maybe you aren't assigning the result of the replaces, so `text = text.Replace..`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to assign the result back to `text`, like:

```
text = text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

Comment: Greattttttttt i was battling with it for nearly 3 hours

Comment: how to remove "\" its not same?

Comment: @Afnan, remember to come here 2 hours and 45 minutes earlier next time then :-)

Comment: Yes, but you need to escape the backslash.

Comment: haha yes well struggling again to remove back slash 
text = Regex.Replace(text , @"\\", "");

Comment: @Afnan, `Regex.Replace`? What's wrong with `text = text.Replace("\\", "")`.

Comment: dosent work actully i am using content that has some Html in string and i am trying to remove these extra backslashes so that it can be used in Html agile pack

Comment: can i get string between two points line it there is a string and i have location of two characters can i get all the string between those points

 int UrlStart = e.Result.IndexOf("<p>");
                  int urlEnd = e.Result.IndexOf("</p>     </td>");

Comment: @Afnan, yes, that can be done with `text.Substring(UrlStart + 3, urlEnd)`

Answer (score 3):

You're close:

```
text = text.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

You have to assign the result of the .Replace operation back to the string itself (or another one).  Otherwise the result goes nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

`text.Replace` returns the newly modified string.  It does not change the string it is operating against.  So make sure you are capturing the return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.Replace("\\\\r","").Replace("\\\\n","");
```

you probably need to use an escape character

Comment: The \ is not literal, \r is an escape sequence that represents a carriage return (0x0D), which together with \n newline (0x0A) is what the op wants to remove, not the literals \ (0x5C) r (0x72) etc.

Comment: You can also use str = str.Replace(@"\r", string.Empty).Replace(@"\n", string.Empty); or simply use the overloaded Replace method with chars like: str.Replace('\r', string.Empty)...

Comment: @tivo, No you cannot.  There is not an overload of `Replace` that takes a `char` and a `string` as the two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")
```

Didn't remove "\r\n" in my input. Then I remembered that \r and \n are special characters which needed to be escaped, hence the following worked for me:

```
.Replace(@"\r", "").Replace(@"\n", "")
```